# Prettier - keep a line break before else

Tags: prettier

This

```
return message;

    } else if (
```

gets formatted into this:

```
return message;
    } else if (
```

Is there a setting that would let me separate the next case from the previous case's code, without disabling handling linebreaks altogether?

Answer (score 0):

There's already an [open issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/840) regarding the same feature with prettier. It's been 3 years with no resolution in sight. You can try [prettierx](https://github.com/brodybits/prettierx) library for less opinionated formatting.